# Authorize helm chart in docker.io

Tags: docker, kubernetes, authorization

Hey i'm trying to authorize my pods in docker.io because i got:

```
Warning  Failed  11m (x3 over 12m)  kubelet  Failed to pull image "busybox:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: toomanyrequests: You have reached your pull rate limit. You may increase the limit by authenticating and upgrading: https://www.docker.com/increase-rate-limit
```

I already have a secret set up:

```
> kubectl get secret regcred

NAME      TYPE                             DATA   AGE
regcred   kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson   1      105m
```

Unfortunately I have no idea where to "throw" it if I pull the whole from chart:

```
> helm2 upgrade --namespace gitlab --install gitlab gitlab/gitlab --timeout 600 -f gitlab-conf.yaml
```

I have gitlab-conf.yaml with the given resources, etc which are on AWS. Do you have any idea?

//Edit: Should I customize chart in some way?

Comment: Hey, I have some difficulty to understand where exactly your issue lies. You are receiving this error when creating some "workload" with Gitlab? I'd reckon you could look on this link: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/charts/gitlab-runner/-/issues/94 . I'd reckon you could also look here (from Kubernetes perspective) on `imagePullSecret`: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/

Answer (score 0):

- The reason you are getting that error message is due to [docker download limit](https://www.docker.com/increase-rate-limits)
- Login into worker node(s) and perform
  `docker login`
  `docker pull busybox:latest`

Comment: Still receive: pod-name      0/1     Init:ImagePullBackOff   0          93s

Comment: it generally takes sometime ... if ```docker pull busybox:latest``` was successful then you can add imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent  under conatiner.spec in helm templates.

Comment: Sorry but that does not answer my question. I rather wanted to update the cluster configuration with the help of a helm chart so that the pods would use the already created secret (regcred). PS still doesn't work